# String to XMLGregorianCalendar issue

Tags: java, string, date, gregorian-calendar

i am trying to convert from string to XML Gregorian Calendar date and its always returning me a new instance, Please check my code below

Input date ::2014-03-13 15:34:33 +0000

Desired Output date :: 2014-03-13 15:34:33 +0000

But when i convert using my code below the output is 2014-03-13T11:34:33.000-04:00

```
   public static void convertXMLGregorian() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    XMLGregorianCalendar xc=DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
    String xcs = df.format(xc.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());        

    XMLGregorianCalendar converted = stringToXMLGregorianCalendar(xcs, df); 
    System.out.println("converted " + converted);
 // output :: 2014-03-13T11:34:33.000-04:00


// String conversion methods 

private static XMLGregorianCalendar dateToXMLGregorianCalendar(Date date) {

    try {

        GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar
                .getInstance();

        gc.setTime(date);

        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);

    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {

        System.out.print(e.getMessage());

        return null;

    }

}


private static XMLGregorianCalendar stringToXMLGregorianCalendar(
        String datetime, SimpleDateFormat sdf) {

    try {

        Date date = sdf.parse(datetime);

        return dateToXMLGregorianCalendar(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        System.out.print(e.getMessage());

        return null;

    }
```

Please Help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the difference in input date and desired output date?

Comment: thats my desired output not the current output, if you see the next line the current output is 2014-03-13T11:34:33.000-04:00

Comment: @user3288434 you're getting the expected date but in different timezone. Just change the timezone in your calendar and you get the *desired* value.

Answer (score 3):

See below for why the existing code isn't working for you, and a workaround. However, to preserve the UTC offset *and* do the whole thing far more simply, I suspect you just want to use [`DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar(java.lang.String)):

```
// This replaces *all* of the code in the question
XMLGregorianCalendar result = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(datetime);
```

The only fly in the ointment here is that it looks like your input doesn't have a `T` in it, whereas the canonical XML representation does. That's easily fixed:

```
// The only place you've got a space is exactly where you want a T.
datetime = datetime.replace(' ', 'T');
XMLGregorianCalendar result = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(datetime);
```

---

**Original answer**

I suspect that this is the problem:

```
GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
```

That will create a calendar *in the default time zone*.

If you always want to have a UTC offset of 0, just use:

```
gc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
```

If you're trying to preserve the UTC offset in the original text, that's a different matter - you can't do that with your current approach, because `Date` doesn't maintain that information. (It's just an instant in time.)

As an aside, I would strongly suggest that you change your exception handling strategy - simply returning `null` and continuing as if all was well is rarely a good idea. It's *usually* a better idea to either let the exception propagate or wrap it in a more suitable exception type (possibly a runtime exception).

Comment: that worked like a charm, thanks and also do you have any suggestions on preserving the offset, 2007-10-31T05:00:00.000Z is the output i got after the change is there a way to change it to something like 2014-03-13T11:34:33.000-04:00 and preserve the offset.

Comment: @user3288434: I've just found what I *suspect* would be a much, much better option - editing it into the answer now.

Comment: Oh yeah the canonical representation does need a T, replacing it resolved my problem, but when i am trying to get the offset yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ its throwing me Error in parsing time zone: '2014-03-13T19:17:41+0000' exception, However its working i use this yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on resolving the offset issue as mentioned in the comment above

Comment: @user3288434: Your comment isn't clear to me... what's the input, and where is the error?

Comment: You suggested me to use DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(String) for preserving the offset, buy when i declare the string format using  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"); i am getting a parse exception.

Comment: @user3288434: Why are you still using `SimpleDateFormat` at all when you can just use `DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar`? This is very confusing... it may be worth asking a new question.

Comment: Note that `newXMLGregorianCalendar(..)` is not a static method as the answer may suggest. Use `DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(..)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("converted " + converted);
```

This will use the toString() method of converted. You might want to use your SimpleDateFormat here?